# Do SMS messages sent through Android's SmsManager appear in the normal Messaging app?

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

Do SMS messages sent through Android's [SmsManager.sendTextMessage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) appear in the normal Messaging app?

My tests suggest not, but I have limited access to devices, and none of them have active connections.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Note: Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), if and only if an app is not selected as the default SMS app, the system automatically writes messages sent using this method to the SMS Provider (the default SMS app is always responsible for writing its sent messages to the SMS Provider).

I can confirm that this is behavior that I've witnessed on all of the devices I've tested on (only 4 or 5 different ones, mostly newer Samsung and LG top end phones).

If you don't want your messages to appear in the stock Messaging app you have to get the user to set your app as the Default Message App.

Comment: Thanks.  Haven't knowingly set my app as the default messaging app, but I am using 4.0.